# Splitting DataTable and converting to HTML Table in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have one table which is converted from datatable to html table inorder to send Email.

```
UserName            EmailID                    Hours

Name             something@example.com           23
Name             something@example.com           65
Name             something@example.com           30
Name             something@example.com           68
Name             something@example.com           29
Name             something@example.com           70
```

I want to modify from this DataTable. I want to split into two sets(datatables or HTML tables), like below 40 Hours is one table and above 60 Hours is one table. Then want to send as two html table in email.

```
 if ((result.Rows[k]["Hours"]) != null && (result.Rows[k]["Hours"]) != "")
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(result.Rows[k]["Hours"].ToString()) >= itemHours || Convert.ToDouble(result.Rows[k]["Hours"].ToString()) <= 60)
                {
                    result.Rows[k].Delete();
                    k = k - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        result.AcceptChanges();
```

result is the final DataTable to Convert to HTML Table. Before sending Mail have to convert to Two HTMl Table like i said before.

Comment: And what did you try ? Please show us some code of your best attempt to achieve this on your own.

Comment: result datatable contains hours rows with lesser than 40 and greater than 60. Now wants to split this as i said in description

Comment: I don't understand if there is some difficulty if you declare two datatables with names dtAbove60 and dtAbove40 and then in loop, use condition to fill them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("EmailID", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("Hours", typeof(System.Int32));

dt.Rows.Add("user1", "abc@abc1.com", 10);
dt.Rows.Add("user2", "abc@abc2.com", 20);
dt.Rows.Add("user3", "abc@abc3.com", 30);
dt.Rows.Add("user4", "abc@abc4.com", 40);
dt.Rows.Add("user5", "abc@abc5.com", 50);
dt.Rows.Add("user6", "abc@abc6.com", 60);
dt.Rows.Add("user7", "abc@abc7.com", 70);
dt.Rows.Add("user8", "abc@abc8.com", 80);
dt.Rows.Add("user9", "abc@abc9.com", 90);
dt.Rows.Add("user10", "aaa@aaa10.com", 100);

string strTable1 = "<table>";
string strTable2 = "<table>";

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int hours = 0;
    int.TryParse(dt.Rows[i]["Hours"].ToString(), out hours);
    if (hours > 60)
    {
        strTable1 += "<tr><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["UserName"] + "</td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["EmailID"] + "</td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Hours"] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    else if (hours < 40)
    {
        strTable2 += "<tr><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["UserName"] + "</td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["EmailID"] + "</td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Hours"] + "</td></tr>";
    }
}

strTable1 += "</table>"; // Above 60 hours
strTable2 += "</table>"; // Below 40 hours
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try using `Linq`. Using Datatables can get very messy when you're wanting to do this sort of thing.

Here's just one (contrived) example (console App):

```
 var people = new List<People>()
            {
                new People { Name = "Mark", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 20 },
                new People { Name = "Test1", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 30 },
                new People { Name = "Test2", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 40 },
                new People { Name = "Test3", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 20 },
                new People { Name = "Test4", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 30 },
                new People { Name = "Test5", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 45 },
                new People { Name = "Test6", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 46 },
                new People { Name = "Test7", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 45 },
                new People { Name = "Test8", Email = "someone@example.com", Hours = 50 }
            };

            var dt = ConvertToDatatable(people);
            var over40 = from s in dt.AsEnumerable()     //We want people over 40 hours
                         where s.Field<int>("Hours") >= 40
                         select s;
            //Stuff this back in a DataTable
            var dtOver40 = ConvertToDatatable(over40.ToList());

            //Under 40
             var under40 = from s in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where s.Field<int>("Hours") < 40
                      select s;
            var dtUnder40 = ConvertToDatatable(under40.ToList());

            foreach(var folks in over40)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(folks[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(folks[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(folks[2]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

This may look a little foreign but in order to set up a quick, working example I used a static method to convert a `List<T>` to a DataTable:

```
 private static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(List<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
                else
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using Linq

```
//First I need to fill the DataTable you have
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("EmailID", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("Hours", typeof(System.Int32));

dt.Rows.Add("user1", "abc@abc1.com", 10);
dt.Rows.Add("user2", "abc@abc2.com", 20);
dt.Rows.Add("user3", "abc@abc3.com", 30);
dt.Rows.Add("user4", "abc@abc4.com", 40);
dt.Rows.Add("user5", "abc@abc5.com", 50);
dt.Rows.Add("user6", "abc@abc6.com", 60);
dt.Rows.Add("user7", "abc@abc7.com", 70);
dt.Rows.Add("user8", "abc@abc8.com", 80);
dt.Rows.Add("user9", "abc@abc9.com", 90);
dt.Rows.Add("user10", "aaa@aaa10.com", 100);

//Get the rows less than 40 with Linq and format them as HTML rows
string[] lessThan40 = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where Convert.ToInt32(row["Hours"]) < 40
                  select string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",
                                row["UserName"], row["EmailID"], row["Hours"])).ToArray();

//Get the rows more than 60 with Linq and format them as HTML rows
string[] moreThan60 = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where Convert.ToInt32(row["Hours"]) > 60
                  select string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",
                                row["UserName"], row["EmailID"], row["Hours"])).ToArray();

//Finally just add the HTML rows generated to the HTML Table element
string htmlTables = string.Format("<table>{0}</table><br><br><table>{1}</table>",
                    string.Join(string.Empty, lessThan40),
                    string.Join(string.Empty, moreThan60));
```